# Issue while reading json from kinesis to pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to read streaming JSON data from Kinesis to PySpark.My JSON looks like:

```
{'installmentNo': '10', 'loanId': '1'}
```

I have specified the schema but I get 'null' when spark reads the data. Below is the code snippet.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json

fields = [

  StructField("installmentNo", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("loanId", IntegerType(), True)

]
pythonSchema = StructType(fields)

kinesisDf = spark.readStream \
.format("kinesis")\
.option("streamName", kinesisStreamName)\
.option("region", kinesisRegion)\
.option("initialPosition", "latest")\
.option("awsAccessKey", awsAccessKeyId)\
.option("awsSecretKey", awsSecretKey).load()

dataDevicesDF = kinesisDf.selectExpr("cast (data as STRING) my_json_data").select(from_json("my_json_data", pythonSchema).alias("yp_inst")).select("yp_inst.*")
display(dataDevicesDF)
```

Output:

[image]

However, when I remove 'from_json' part, I get a single column with JSON string. But I want to explode the json into specific columns and get the data as df. Can someone suggest me the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema is incorrect - your data is string, while you declare integers.

Please change the definition to

```py
pythonSchema = StructType([
    StructField("installmentNo", StringType(), True),
    StructField("loanId", StringType(), True)
])
```

and cast the output:

```py
from_json(
    "my_json_data", pythonSchema
).cast("struct<installmentNo: integer, loanId: integer>"))
```

The rest of the code should stay as-is, although for clarity you could explicitly set options (as the input is not a standard JSON):

```py
from_json(
    "my_json_data", pythonSchema, {"allowSingleQuotes": "true"}
).cast("struct<installmentNo: integer, loanId: integer>"))
```